# Extract configuraiton files from raspbian image

Tags: backup, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I backed up my raspbian using Win32DiskImager. Later, I noticed that my Raspberry Pi did not boot because the SD card was damaged. I tried to restore the backup but still the Raspberry Pi did not boot. I formatted the card, installed a new raspbian image and everything now works fine.
Is there a way to somehow "mount" the image of my backed up old SD card and exctract some configuration files from it without having to boot the Raspberry?

Extract configuraiton files from raspbian image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is worth trying to do this under windows because it does not play nice with **ext4,** which is the main partition in the raspbian image.  What typically happens is it isn't recognized at all, and people are confused by the one small **fat32** partition containing the kernel, bootloader, some firmware, etc.

I've described [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13137/how-can-i-mount-a-raspberry-pi-linux-distro-image/13138#13138) how to examine and mount the two partitions typically used on raspberry pi distros (including raspbian) with linux commands.  It boils down to:

```
mount -v -o offset=62914560 -t ext4 whatever.img /mnt/img/two
```

But do read the full instructions as your offset might be different.  If you don't have a linux system besides the pi, download a liveCD.  Your life in so far as it involves the pi will be much easier that way.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to do this on my debian virtual machine. I don't know why this image doesn't work when I install it to an sd card. I hope it is not damaged.

Answer (score 0):

If you have additional USB key, use Unix tool `dd`:

```
# dd bs=4M if=path_to_.img of=/dev/letter_of_USB
```

Now, on USB, you have exacted image of your backup. I think it's also possible with `Win32DiskImager`. You should exact .img to USB key.

Comment: Ah but enedil, there's *two* partitions in the image...

Comment: `dd` would create partitions like on .img file.

Comment: Yes.  But you still need to answer the question ;)  I believe the OP is referring to an *already existing* `.img`.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to an existing .img that, when put into a SD card, makes the raspberry unable to boot.

Comment: @goldilocks It is an answer. You do that and on the USB, you can get important files. For other info `man dd`.

Comment: @enedil It's an answer to the question "How can I create an image of a block device?" but that's not what this question is.  The OP already has such an image, s/he is asking how to access the filesystems inside of it.  Since it's an image of *a block device* -- and not *a filesystem partition* -- you can't simply mount it the way you would mount an `.iso` of a filesystem.  You need to locate the beginning of the filesystem(s) inside the block device image first.